# SMTPSenderRefused at /Contact/ (530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0

Tags: python, django, email, gmail

I want the users of my website after the login with gmail account using the google api to send to the account1@gmail.com  email after entring the name and the email address and the message  in the contact.html but i get this error despite i have activated the 2 factor authentication for the account1@gmail.com and create a password for my website .
this is my function  contact in my views.py:

```
 def contact(request):

    if request.method=='POST':

        message_name=request.POST['message-name']

        message_email=request.user.email

        message=request.POST['message']

        print(message_email)

        send_mail(

            message_name,

            message,

            message_email,

            ['account1@gmail.com'],

            fail_silently=False

        )



        return render(request,'store/Contact.html',{'message_name':message_name})

    else:

        return render(request,'store/Contact.html',{}
```

and this the settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND="django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"

EMAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'



EMAIL_PORT=587

EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='password_of_the_app'

EMAIL_USE_TLS=True

EMAIL_USE_SSL=False





AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (

 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

 'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',

 )



SITE_ID= 14

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL= '/'
```

but when i add the EMAIL_HOST_USER='account1@gmail.com' i can send the email from the account1@gmail.com to account1@]gmail.com but not from the email feild that exist in my template.

really any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Go to your google account.
2. Go to security.
3. Turn on Less Secure App Access.
4. Add this in your `settings.py`

   `EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'your email'`

   `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your password'`